# Search for a string may containing spaces and special characters in the specific type of files in entire directory structure

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, search, space

I have following batch script to check the specific type of files, in entire directory structure from the current directory, if a string is found in those files or not:

```cmd
@echo off
set RESULT_FILE="result.txt"
set /p STR="Enter the String to Find: "
pushd %~p0
type NUL > %RESULT_FILE%.tmp
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S *.phtml') do (
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%c in ('find /i /c ".%STR:"=%." "%%a"') do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('find /i ".%STR:"=%." "%%a"') do if %%c neq 0 echo %%f
    )
) >> "%RESULT_FILE%".tmp
move %RESULT_FILE%.tmp %RESULT_FILE% >nul 2>&1

:: Open the file
"%RESULT_FILE%"
popd
```

But my search string may contain spaces between multiple words and special characters too.

How can I modify the search string variable `STR` to allow spaces and special characters in the search string as literal?

Right now zero results are returned when the search string contains spaces and special characters.

Comment: At first I would remove quotes from the `STR` variable in advance rather than within the´`for /F` command lines. Why are you prepending and appending a `.` to the search strings?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work. I remove the quotes before the `for` loop, but only the outer, how it works is explained [here at ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-dequote.html). To work with special characters like a carret (`^`) I enabled delayed expansion.
Further it won't work with prepending and appending `.` in the search string, I don't know why you've added it.
I've also added a `/A-D` so that the `dir` command will not list directory names.

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set RESULT_FILE="result.txt"
set /p STR="Enter the String to Find: "

:: Remove just outer quotes not quotes that are inside
set STR=###!STR!###
set STR=!STR:"###=!
set STR=!STR:###"=!
set STR=!STR:###=!

pushd %~p0
type NUL > %RESULT_FILE%.tmp
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S /A-D *.phtml') do (
   for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%c in ('find /i /c "%STR%" "%%a"') do (
      for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('find /i "%STR%" "%%a"') do if %%c neq 0 echo %%f
   )
) >> "%RESULT_FILE%".tmp
move %RESULT_FILE%.tmp %RESULT_FILE% >nul 2>&1

:: Open the file
"%RESULT_FILE%"
popd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but it prints the paths in caps letters, instead of original path letters, can they be fixed ?

Comment: @VST: It's the output of `find`. To "fix" that you have to concate the path and the finding for your self if there is a finding.

Comment: Hi @VST if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.